# In AS3 / Flash Can a URL Request / Loader Use "//" without Specifying a http or https Protocol?

Tags: actionscript-3, ssl, protocols

I have a flash app running that loads remote data and we're transitioning to use (SSL) https://

I am wondering is it possible to just use "//" as you would in JavaScript to automatically assume the parent page's protocol (http or https).

Thanks

**update:** it seems to me that you can use a url format like "//www.something.com" but instead of  assuming the page protocol it seems like it's just defaulting to "http://www.something.com".

Now I'm working around this by checking if the SWF is an SSL url. Something like this:

```
if( loaderInfo.url.indexOf("https:") == 0 ) {
    //replace http: with https:
}
```

Which is unfortunately inconvenient to be doing that everywhere you handle a remote asset URL.  Just loading everything with matching proto would be a lot nicer... like "//www.someurl.com/wouldbenicer.xml", especially since js and html both work that way.

Blah.

Any ideas?

Comment: No I've only searched the adobe docs and forums and stack overflow posts.  My problem is that the app is being transitioned so all the important calls are already breaking because of SSL and Non-SSL URLs.  Using the relative proto would be a big help but I can't find docs on it anywhere.  I want to make sure the things we implement are supported before implementing them, even if they work "today", you never know with FlashPlayer updates and so many versions and security sandbox errors...

Comment: Try it :)  One clue to all of this, is that Flash uses your browser to make http (or https) requests. I don't think I'm going out on a limb by saying that Javascript does the same. So any type of URL that works in the browser or Javascript should work in Flash :)

Comment: By the way what is "//"? When I use relative URLs I prefix them with either one slash or no slash at all. Just curious...

Comment: "//" is a way to start a URL where it assumes the protocol of the page that it's on (http: or https:) instead of hard-coding it, so that you can support SSL and non-SSL with the same URL

Comment: That's strange that it behaves that way. I am pretty sure it does the right thing protocol wise when using relative URLs with one or no slashes. A Flash player bug, perhaps? Thanks for explaining the double slash :)

Comment: On a side note, // is the way most CDN includes are done so that they'll work on SSL or non-SSL pages. It's very common with jquery include, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"//" relative proto doesn't work in flash the way the browser works with urls in HTML, instead it defaults to http://

**Workaround:**

Check the URL of the SWF to see if the URL about to be loaded should be modified to have https:// protocol:

```
 if( loaderInfo.url.indexOf("https:") == 0 ) {
     //replace http: with https:
 } else {
   //replace https: with http:
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Building upon OG Sean's answer, here's a wrapper function that'll manage protocol-relative URLs and default to HTTP.

```
function relativeURL(url:String) {
    var scheme = (loaderInfo.url.indexOf("https:") == 0) ? "https:": "http:";
    var url = scheme + url.replace(/^https?:/,"");
    return url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using a string contains splash, and add it twice

```
var singlesplash:String = "/";
var doublesplash:String = singlesplash + singlesplash;
myurl = "http:" + doublesplash + "www.google.com";
```

or

```
myurl = "http:/" + "/www.google.com";
```

Comment: The question was not how to concatenate a string with two slashes, it was if you load a URL in AS3 that starts with "//" will the browser do what it does in HTML, which is assume the protocol of the current page (http: vs https:)

This is helpful when some of your site runs SSL (https:// urls) and other parts non-SSL (http://) but you have urls to images or CSS files in a common header or footer across all parts and you want the protocols to match.